# Does IMP imp = imp_implementationWithBlock((void*) objc_unretainedPointer(^(id me, BOOL selected)

Tags: objective-c-runtime

The following provides a convenient way to add methods to a class at runtime:

```
imp_implementationWithBlock((void*) objc_unretainedPointer(^(id me, BOOL selected)
```

The method can then be added using class_addMethod(). Will these implementations eventually become cached and use the fast-track method dispatching system?

Comment: No answers yet, but it seems that it does. . . leaving the question open in case someone has some deeper insights.

Comment: These function calls by themselves don't add a method to a class. Assuming that you're using `class_addMethod()` afterwards, why would you expect this case (`IMP` from Block) to behave differently than any other case?

Comment: You're right, I should've asked if class_addMethod() ends up using the fast-track. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My gut feeling would be yes, because doing otherwise would complicate the delicate, consistent, and beautiful Objective-C runtime :)

Also this link -> http://kevin.sb.org/2006/11/16/objective-c-caching-and-method-swizzling/

Seems pretty confident. They're all Method's in the Class after you call class_addMethod. As far as I can tell, please correct me if I'm wrong, there's no way to distinguish them from ones which were compiled in.

Comment: Not quite a definitive answer, however, I think you're correct.